# Auto Create Foreign Key

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 table that is `task` and `tasktracking`. In my `task` table, I have my `task_id` and `task` while `tasktracking` has `tracking_id` and `task_id`.

The `task_id` in my `tasktracking` table is a foreign key to the primary key of `task` table.

Every time when I add a task in my website, the data goes to the `task` table. (cause my task_id is auto increment). So the `tasktracking` table won't auto create any record that causes I can't make use of it in my tracking page. Is there any way to write the sql query to send my `task_id` to the tracking table in the same time or any setting I can make to my sql databse like unique key or something so it can like 'auto create the data'?

I use php by the way.

my database image 
[tasktracking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbgmq.png)
[task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqDPp.png)

Comment: Considering the phpMyAdmin screenshots, you're using MySQL, right ? Check [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: @ Ashisuto Technology
Once your insertion query completed then you can access the last insert id. You can use this last inserted id and insert it into tasktracking table.

Mysql way to get last insert id:
mysql > SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

Comment: @kamal is this works when there is multi user using the same database?

Comment: @Cid Is this last insert thing like ( first I complete the query to insert into the task table, then I use it as `SELECT` and save it in a $id then write another query to insert into the tasktracking table?

Comment: Yes, That is the way you need to implement this. Yes, it will for the multi-user if they use the same database at the same time because database input depends on the DB session. For each session, there will be a different session id and there will be no conflict with the users.

Comment: Yes, as long as you don't close the connection between the queries

Comment: @Cid do I just insert the data into the tasktracking or I need to use fetch_assoc() first?

Comment: something like ```$sq = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM task";

$result = $conn->query($sq) or die($conn->error);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $text = $row['task_id'];
    echo $text;
}```

Comment: [`$conn->insert_id`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) should be enough. I'm sure this question was asked tons of times

Comment: Or, the crude way, run a query to insert all id's from `task` not existing in `task_tracking`, like `INSERT IGNORE INTO task_tracking (task_id) SELECT DISTINCT task_id FROM task`